# Help setting up a set of nonlinear DEs for numerical solver

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, nonlinear-system

I am looking to solve the following nonlinear differential equations:

$c = cos(\alpha), s = sin(\alpha); R, W, p, L, \mu, m_1, m_2$ are all constants.

(1) $$ \frac{-spWR\exp(\mu (\beta - \alpha))}{m_2} = \dot \alpha^2(-Rc -Ls + R\beta s - R\alpha s + 2Rc) + \ddot \alpha(-Rs +Lc -R\beta c + R\alpha c + Rs) - 2\dot \alpha \dot \beta Rc - \ddot \beta Rs $$ 
(2)

$$ \frac{-cpWR\exp(\mu (\beta - \alpha))}{m_2} = \dot \alpha^2(-Rs +Lc - R\beta c + R\alpha c + 2Rs) + \ddot \alpha(Rc +Ls -R\beta s + R\alpha s - Rc) - 2\dot \alpha \dot \beta Rs + \ddot \beta Rc $$

(3)

$$\frac12 m_1R^2\ddot \beta = -pWR^2\exp(\mu (\beta - \alpha))$$

I am trying to figure out how I would go about solving this numerically. I'm trying to use MATLAB ODE45 but I don't know how to get these equations into first order for the ODE45 solver. Is there a way that I can manipulate these equations so that I can put them in a nonlinear DE solver?

Comment: You have 3 equations for 2 unknown functions. Are you sure these are compatible? Is there a third unknown function besides $α$ and $β$?

Comment: You equations can be simplified to \begin{align}
sf(β−α)&=\dot α^2[Rc-(L-R(β−α))s]+\ddot α(L-R(β−α))c-2\dot α\dot βRc+\ddot βRs\\
cf(β−α)&=\dot α^2[Rs+(L-R(β−α))c]+\ddot α(L-R(β−α))s-2\dot α\dot βRs+\ddot βRc\\
\end{align}
By computing linear combinations with factors $(c,-s)$ and $(-s,c)$, and $c_2=\cos(2α)$, $s_2=\sin(2α)$,
\begin{align}
0&=\dot α^2[Rc_2-(L-R(β−α))s_2]+\ddot α(L-R(β−α))c_2-2\dot α\dot βRc_2\\
c_2f(β−α)&=\dot α^2(L-R(β−α))+\ddot βRc_2\\
\end{align}
you can build a first order system. There may be sign errors, the occurrence of double angles is suspicious to me.